# How to exclude non-word char in the middle of a word when regex expression \b is in use

Tags: javascript, regex

For a string like `"abc'md a li-xtl isdf sdf"`, if I use the regex `/\b\w/g`, it matches `'m` and `-x` also because `'` and `-` are non-word chars. I want only the first char in each new word. I am using a workaround regex `/^\w|\s\w/g` but not sure if that is the best possible choice. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:^|\s)(\w)
```

You can use this and grab the `group`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mG8kZ9/17

Answer (score 0):

You should use a non-capturing group : `/(?:\b)\w/g`

here is a good website to extend your knowledge of regex : https://regex101.com/

```js
var s = "abc'md a li-xtl isdf sdf";
document.write(s);
document.write("<br>");
document.write(s.match(/(?:\b)\w/g,"\1"));
```

Comment: Your solution is still giving the output which I want to avoid. The output is a,m,a,l,x,i,s whereas I need a,a,l,i,s

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following regex:

```
([A-Za-z]{1})\S*
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, the contraction and hyphenation problem. Probably best to make those explicitly "word" characters then, and avoid the regexp definition of \w (and \b):

```
/(?<![-'a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z]/g
```

Assumes your "words" can't start with -, ', or numbers also.

Update: Above is PCRE, below is a JS solution:

```
/(?:^|[^-'a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z])/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/vJ9iO5/2

Comment: Looks like there is invalid group structure due to `<` in `(?<`. I am running each suggested regex on https://regex101.com to find the most suitable answer.

Comment: No, it does work there: https://regex101.com/r/vJ9iO5/1  You have to enter the ! as well.

Comment: Correction, sorry, you need JS and I've got PCRE, so yeah.